# Mock method for all instances of enum java

Tags: java, android, unit-testing

I want to mock the method shouldShow() for all instances of an enum. Can someone help on how to do it.

```
public enum MyButton implements ListButton {
    Button1(
        R.drawable.drawable1) {
             // Some methods here
    },
    Button2(
            R.drawable.drawable2) {
        //Some methods here
    };

    @Override
    public boolean shouldShow() {
        //Some logic that decides whether to show the button or not
    }
}
```

I want to mock it such that if I call Button1.shouldShow or Button2.shouldShow, or any other value in the enum.shouldShow, my stub should return true.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by doing this? My understanding is that you can't mock enums in this way, but generally you can still achieve your desired testing in other ways.

Comment: The shouldShow method contains a bunch of statics. I know I can test the function using powermock, but I will have to mock a lot of statics. I am trying to avoid doing it, be somehow mocking the shouldShow function itself.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding; that wasn't what I was asking. In your test case, where you're trying to mock this method, what are you testing? What is the broader goal of that test case?

Comment: The broad goal is to test whether I am able to inflate a particular layout correctly or now. My inflate method calls a bunch of private methods, one of which calls this shouldShow method to check whether this button be shown or not. Now, I can't avoid calling that private method, neither can I mock that method because its private. So I wanted to mock calls to this shouldShow method, because I don't really care about whether this button is shown or not, because its not what I'm really testing.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the `shouldShow()` method is part of the `ListButton` interface. If your design is well thought-out, you should most likely be mocking a `ListButton`, not what happens for any particular `MyButton`.

Java enums constants are essentially public static final fields, so mocking the `shouldShow()` method on the particular `MyButton` constants amounts to mocking a method on a static final field.